# Permission denied to SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION on Amazon Postgres RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-permissions

For my application, I sometimes need to set session authorization to execute certain commands under a given user's permissions.

We're using an RDS behind the application, and our DB superuser on RDS keeps getting `permission denied to set session authorization`.

Is there a way to enable this on an RDS? Or is it just not a supported operation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I could do `set role` in rds - can you adapt logic to `set role` instead?.. but first try if you can set role with `rds_superuser`, as cant check myself - weekend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

alas, limitations of rds_superuser [are not documented](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html)

> The rds_superuser role is a pre-defined Amazon RDS role similar to the
>   PostgreSQL superuser role (customarily named postgres in local
>   instances), but with some restrictions. As with the PostgreSQL
>   superuser role, the rds_superuser role **has the most privileges on your
>   DB instance**

So if you get `permission denied` with rds_superuser, you probably just can't do it... (as some more better known limitations, like ownership override, fs related functions, limited extensions list and so on)